# Generate reflowable printable documents within a web app

Tags: javascript, asp.net, printing, ms-word, documents

I'm building a web app that allows printing of receipts and dozens of other documents. The documents must be **reflowable** (like MS Word, or HTML, such that inserting text content increases/decreases the number of pages the document uses), and must use a **MS word template** or similar.

**Using a PDF Generator**

For example if I use a PDF generator lib like [AspPDF](http://www.asppdf.com/) or [JsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf), you need to add text content into the PDF by coding, eg:

```
pdf.AddPara("Reciept for " + prodName);
pdf.AddTable("...");
```

This solution is fine, but does not allow the billing folks to create their own document templates in MS Word or similar, and is tedious to add styling and other elements.

**Using HTML**

Export Word to HTML and modify the HTML at runtime and have it print. Easy. Print directly from the browser. But needs cross-browser testing and cannot be exported to PDF fully on the serverside.

**Using PDF**

Export Word to PDF, and somehow insert text into the PDF on the serverside/client side. Tricky, not reflowable, must be downloaded before can be printed. Is natively PDF so can be saved to disk.

**So...**

What are the ways to start with a template document, insert text, have it reflow and dynamically increase the page count, and save it to a HTML/PDF format such that it can be printed easily?

I'm asking first for approaches, although if you know a lib that could do this it would be fine aswell.